Aligning category boxes on top of each other in tikz
I am trying to essentially create a classification tree where I start with the entire set and split it into parts (kind of like a snakey diagram but with less fuss). For this I wanted to create a diagram with boxes that fill portions of the width. The current state looks like this:

with code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={draw, align=center, minimum height=1cm},
    label/.style={font=\small\itshape}
]

% Top box spanning the entire width
\node[box, minimum width=\textwidth] (all_params) {All Parameters};

% Middle boxes splitting the width equally, aligned to the left
\node[box, below=1cm of all_params.west, anchor=west, minimum width=0.5\textwidth] (efficient) {Efficient};
\node[box, right=0pt of efficient.east, anchor=west, minimum width=0.5\textwidth] (redundant) {Redundant};

% Bottom boxes under Efficient, aligned to the left
\node[box, below=1cm of efficient.west, anchor=west, minimum width=0.4\textwidth] (poly_eff) {Polynomially Efficient};
\node[box, right=0pt of poly_eff.east, anchor=west, minimum width=0.1\textwidth] (unknown) {?};

% Bottom boxes under Redundant, aligned to the left
\node[box, below=1cm of redundant.west, anchor=west, minimum width=0.4\textwidth] (general_redundant) {General Redundant};
\node[box, right=0pt of general_redundant.east, anchor=west, minimum width=0.1\textwidth] (activation) {Activation};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I am not very familiar with tikz - the code was partially generated with chatGPT and then modified towards this. I can not remove the minimum part of minimum width without a compiler error so I am unsure how to ensure that the widths of the "General redundant" and "Activation" blocks are (in sum) the same size as the "Redundant" block.
Part of the issue also seems to be the width of the borders of the blocks.

I's use a table instead of tikz

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that would be a good option if I didn't want to continue the graph at the end with some arrows but I will keep that in mind. I also think I understood part of the issue: the "activation" block is too wide for the minimum width. What is left are the borders of the blocks

Have a look at the nicematrix package. Basically a table with build in nodes for all cells, which you can then use to continue your image.

If there are a lot of graphic annotations (that you don't show here),
I would use tcolorbox (tcbitemize) with the key 'enhanced', which allows any TikZ. If you want it to use brute force TikZ, just use a TikZ matrix. Arranging nodes individually is far too time-consuming.

I'd like to strongly discourage using CGPT, e.g. in coding. More often than not the results look nice at first glance, but oftentimes don't survive a simple compile run. Often it used quite old sources. // In your code there is some redundancy from positioning and anchor ... you could do all that with just anchoring. // We like to help; however I don't see myself as a CGPT-debugger. // If in doubt, train your brain ...  E.g. by the tutorials here: https://tikz.dev/, and a search in this place every now and then. // E.g. start by looking up all those Tikz keywords from your code.

@MS-SPO the issue are the unknown unknowns. I typically do not even know what to google for in the case of tikz so the generated code is a good starting point because then I can look up what individual parts actually do. I simply do not have the time to read the entire tikz documentation and I don't use it enough that much of it would stick. So yeah, I looked up the keywords. The original generated code looked much worse

I went with samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's suggestion and used the nicematrix package

The following standalone code does not quite work, since the nicetable seems to define the canvas and everything below that is cutoff. But in the case of the actual document I could solve that with a manual \vspace. I am also not completely happy with the origin of the arrows but it is good enough.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd, pgfplots} % plots and sketches
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\activation}{\psi}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sigmoid}{sigmoid}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ *{6}{c} }[corners, hvlines]
    \Block{1-6}{All possible parameters}\\
    \Block[borders=right]{1-2}{Efficient} & & \Block{1-4}{Redundant} & & & \\
    Polynomially efficient & ? & \Block{1-3}{General redundant} &&& Activation \\
    & & Deactivation & Bias & Duplication & Symmetry \\
    \CodeAfter
        % \TikzEveryCell{offset=1pt,draw}
        \tikz \node[below=4em of 3-1, align=center,xshift=-1em] (isolated) {isolated crit.\ points\\ (Theorem~\ref{thm: morse function on efficient networks})};
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (3-1.south) -- node[fill=white,align=center,text=black!70] {a.s.\\for MSE} (isolated) ;

        \tikz \node[below=6em of 3-2, align=center] (not_poly_efficient) {empty set\\ (Theorem~\ref{thm: characterization of efficient networks})};
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (3-2.south) -- node[fill=white,text=black!70] {\(\activation\in \{\substack{\sigmoid\\\tanh}\}\)} (not_poly_efficient);

        \tikz \node[below=3.3em of 4-4.south, align=center] (not_exists) {crit. points do not exist\\(Proposition~\ref{prop: bias red do not exist})};
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (4-4.south) -- node[fill=white,align=center,text=black!70] {a.s. for MSE} (not_exists);

        \tikz \node[below=5em of 4-6.south, anchor=north, align=center,text=black!70] (not_isolated) {crit. points never isolated\\(Theorem~\ref{})};
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (4-5.south) -- (not_isolated);
        \tikz \draw[-Stealth] (4-6.south) -- node[fill=white,xshift=1em,text=black!70] {\(\activation\in \{\substack{\sigmoid\\\tanh}\}\)} (not_isolated);
\end{NiceTabular}



\end{document}


You may want to look for and use the /.style={…} syntax to simplify your code.
